# Get Custom Multiple Field Value with Custom Submit Action

Tags: jss, sitecore-forms

I am trying to implemented custom multiple fields with `Sitecore Forms` using `Sitecore JSS`. The UI is working as expected.

This is my Sitecore Form design
[image]

And this is the result.
[image]

The problem occurs when I submit the Form, I can't get the value of each field in `formSubmitContext` class with custom submit action.
Navigating to the browser developer tools, I can see the values in FormData Section.

These are the payload formdata in browser tools

[image]

Comment: Post screenshot from browser Developer Tools of all the data sent while submitting the form.

Comment: Updated the with the screenshoot

Comment: You're adding some custom suffixes to your fields, e.g. `-02-12`. I don't think Sitecore will be able to map them automatically for you.

Comment: Can you also add the code of your custom submit action?

Comment: Can't when I look into the custom submit action using this method "protected override bool Execute(string data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext) {.....}" 
formSubmitContext captured the original ID from the Sitecore form.
But the customID is not captured in the custom submit action.

Comment: @PTechCode did you find a solution for this

Comment: Not yet, I struggle field id it can't duplicate was challenged.